# Enforce value type semantics/immutability in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, immutability

Looking at our code base, I see many cases, where fields of derived types make you expect them to remain unchanged once initialized and ideally, to be initialized all at once and never changed afterwards (like a "value type").

In practice, quick solutions have built up, such that whether a field changes or even what it contains may depend on the code path, leading to large IF-ELSE cascades everywhere, making the code hard to follow and brittle against changes.

This made me wonder: Is it possible to enforce constraints such as immutability of fields?

Comment: There's no concept of "a variable cannot change value once it's been set once" (even for components), but do encapsulation methods (private components with getters) suit your needs?

Comment: @francescalus Not really, since often the fields are arrays. Returning a copy of the array would be inefficient, returning a pointer would require being able to mark that pointer as "points to immutable thing", and as far as I know there is no way to access arrays through an accessor function in a manner that allows slicing syntax.

Comment: What kinds of operations do you need to perform on these derived types? If it is a fairly small number of them can you write a library of routines which does them?

Comment: You could make the array component protected and set it only from a setter. That would prevent changing it from other modules.

Comment: You can use the `PROTECTED` attribute to restrict the ability to modify a variable that is `USE` associated.  Then only procedures within the module where the variable is declared can manipulate the variable.

Comment: Protected always seems a little bit of a disappointment to me, I really want it to apply to a derived type definition to mean that all variables of that type can only be modified by the containing module, not just variables of that type which are use associated - "global" variables make me twitchy. And I think this would be closer to what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned protected for the component, but that is not possible. I think it is one of the proposal for a future standard.

Comment: The main issue really is communication. If I had something like `IMMUTABLE TYPE`, that would clearly communicate to colleagues to not add mutable fields to that type (e.g. logger state information), and also provide obvious guarantees for whoever reads code using that type in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "parameter" key word to make a variable a constant.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_constants.htm

```
real, parameter :: g = 9.81
```

You would have to know the values at compile time so this may not be what you're looking for. If it's not, could you give us some clarification and we can try to help you?

************EDIT******************

As others have stated above, if you need to be able to set the variable at runtime, then getters and setters are the way to go.

You can either make the variable private and write a getter and a setter for it or if you make the variable protected then you only need to write a setter for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for derived type components.

Comment: You could make the entire derived type instance a constant.

Comment: I do not think Anon needs that, but they can tell us themselves.

Comment: Not what I am looking for; I know well enough about compile-time constants (which by the way DOES work for derived types, as long as they have static size), but I am looking for something akin to the "const" keyword in Javascript, C, C++: The value is calculated at run-time, but there are static guarantees about it not changing after assignment.